# Returned string and fetched string do not match

Tags: c++, string

I have defined the following function to do some operations on a string and return the result:

```
string Message()
{
string result = "";
int l;

    result += "1";
    for(l = 0; l < routers; l++)
    {
        result += " " + table[l];

    }
    cout<<result<<endl;
return result;
}
```

However when I fetch(if I can name it fetch) the returned result in a while loop, and print it out, they are not the same!!

```
while(true)
{    
string a = Message();
cout<<a<<endl;

//do some operation
}
```

Results:

```
1 12 13 15 21 1 (printed out before exiting the function)
1 12 13 15 21 (after fetching)
```

What could be the reason?

Comment: Your code looks fine. Are you *sure* this is all correct?

Comment: Show a real program that exhibits the problem.

Comment: The real program adapts a select function and sends the message in the variable a to other clients.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your code in "other operation" modifies the global variable `routers` or, less likely, the variable Table.

Good luck!

Comment: No, neither the routers and Table variable will be touched during the program execution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's wrong with some systems, but for me I changed the part "l < routers" to "l <= routers" and it's working well now! They both produce the same result!

```
string Message()
{
string result = "";
int l;

result += "1";
for(l = 0; l <= routers; l++)
{
    result += " " + table[l];

}
cout<<result<<endl;
return result;
}
```

Comment: I don't know what is the reason behind this, but when I used to get the function's result in that 'while' loop, it didn't return the results completely.